# Web Scraping Yahoo Industry

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am learning web scraping. I was able to pull data from the https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL page. But it doesn't work when I try to pull from the profile page https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/profile?p=AAPL.

```
import bs4 as bs
import requests

r = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/profile?p=AAPL')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml',from_encoding='utf-8')

industry = soup.find_all('div',attrs={'id':'Main'})[0].find(attrs={'data-reactid':'25'}).get_text()

print(industry)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-3edd92f273ed> in <module>
      5 soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml',from_encoding='utf-8')
      6 
----> 7 industry = soup.find_all('div',attrs={'id':'Main'})[0].find(attrs={'data-reactid':'25'}).get_text()
      8 
      9 print(industry)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

It's supposed to get consumer electronics.
Industry: Consumer Electronics

I am not sure why it would be out of range since I click inspect on the word itself, and then find an id that encompasses the reactid for consumer electronics. I tried a few of the id list including Main, but it keeps showing index out of range.

And is there a way to get multiple tickers' industry rather than just doing a ticker at a time? Thank you!

Comment: Avoid web-scrapping, instead give this a try [`yfinance`](https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/)

Comment: first you should get `find_all`, next you should check if it has values, and finally you can use `[0]`. But page may use `JavaScript` to add elements and `BeautifulSoup`/`requests` can't run `JavaScript` and it would need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run `JavaScript` - but it can be difficult so better use modules like `yfinance`